# ASCII value not giving correct letters

Tags: c, ascii

I am a beginner.

I have written a program in c using eclipse. It does not give me any error and warnings while compiling and also not after executing it.
It prints out all ASCII values of all characters.

code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){

  int a=0;
  system("clear");
  printf("\nthese are the ASCII values of characters given in front of them\n");
  while(a<=255)
  {
    printf("%c %d \n",a,a);

    a=a+1;

  }
}
```

The output is strange, when I copy paste the output it disappears, thus this is [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zMhb.png) of the screen-shot of the output.
I can't take screen-shot of the whole screen, but after 126 the characters look like boxes. Is there something wrong in my code?

Comment: no. the first 32 chars in ascii are not printable. try this with _int a = 32;_ and see what you get

Comment: @CIsForCookies and what about those above 127? are they printable?

Comment: above 127? in ascii?

Comment: @linuxman That depends on the character encoding of your terminal. If you use for example CP437, then yes, these are printable characters. but in general, no

Comment: This is not a question about C but about linux terminals...

Comment: ASCII only goes up to 127.

Comment: @CIsForCookies yes. the hint of the problem say that "ascii values vary from 0 to 255" the book is "let us c"

Comment: so should i take it as a printing mistake?

Comment: I don't know that book. From what I know, ascii ends at 127. There are extensions such as http://www.ascii-code.com/ but as far as the term _ascii_ goes, I think it means only up to 127

Comment: You didn't tell us yet, what you expected to see on your screen.

Comment: @SiggiSv ASCII is 7-bit and only goes to 127, but most computers today support and use Extended ASCII which is 8-bit and goes to 255.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many characters are unprintable, some are control codes for the terminal/console that enact actions such as clear screen, move the cursor, clear line... etc.

Use the `isprint` function defined in `ctype.h` to determine if the character is printable. A for loop would suit your requirements here better also, see below example.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main(){

  system("clear");
  printf("\nthese are the ASCII values of characters given in front of them\n");
  int a;
  for(a = 0; a <= 255; ++a)
  {
    printf("%c %d \n", isprint(a) ? a : '.', a);
  }
}
```